# Camera Access problem in Amazon EC2 Windows Instance while running Opencv-Python Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-ec2, webcam, rdp

- Actually, I am using OpenCV in my amazing group project. It's basically a Django Web App with DL Models, OpenCV, etc. It needs access to the WEBCAM of the user. Our WebApp works fine in the Local System (On our PC).
- I am using **RDP** to connect to an **AWS EC2 Windows** Instance and I want my local webcam to work on the EC2 instance.
- When I am trying to deploy our Project, our program is unable to execute
  the OPENCV Script i.e. It was not able to open up the Webcam. It shows the following error message :

`(-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`

After research on web & forums I came to know that, This arises if the webcam is not accessible/ path of the Images are incorrect. **Then to verify this I ran a simple python script as follows:**

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not (cap.isOpened()):
    print("Could not open video device")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: # use ESC to quit
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**As I expected, The problem is that OpenCV is unable to access the webcam and thus gave the below output for the above code:**

```
Could not open video device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\webcam.py", line 9, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-i1s8y2i1\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Then I came to the conclusion that I need to make some changes in settings while connecting through the RDP to my AWS Windows EC2 Instance and followed the procedure as described [here.](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-allow-usb-webcam-passthrough-rdp-session#:%7E:text=Open%20up%20mstsc.exe%20or,capture%20devices%E2%80%9D%20%3E%20%E2%80%9CUSB2.)

But still, I am unable to resolve it. I would be too grateful if someone could help me resolve this bug.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you expect something to access your local webcam when the program runs on some server on the internet? it's a web app. the video has to be moved from your local webcam to your browser, and from your browser to the web server.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks a lot for your quick response. I will try it out.